# node bcryptjs not deterministic?

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I used brypt once for password authentication. For some reasons I can't install it on several machines anymore. Anyway I installed bcryptjs instead.

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
const hash = bcrypt.hashSync("hallo", salt);
console.log(hash);
```

I ran the code six times and got these six outputs:

```
$2a$10$SnIj6q67OvPXINLeajqONebAjZltLwrqs8OU/5C871NyTib.SJeyu
$2a$10$8aLhlLvYi5RcuV40SansxOuQroS.SPmPG6GMjsRlcndjjzRSJkFRu
$2a$10$wZJCuAUwtG9v.oh8tgZ9M.unYBe/MRv0jO3IU51gLz8XI1ClYJni6
$2a$10$mGhPf85kGpn/PBdV3JjDsuXypnQ.E2pBTEoDtDZ/eW6qsq5DAb6M6
$2a$10$WkEro4eOiuqzE0.hB/ka2eyPUpWE/Dv5dWkqSZ3yujQ2PA3iRYJMC
$2a$10$l4GVALWSvWdcOin37WXsQeIufA7SHxvhU.9dIasXspsSPi1e1/IeG
```

but this additional code compare it actually the right way

```
const hallo = bcrypt.compareSync("hallo", hash);
console.log(hallo);  //always true
const burger = bcrypt.compareSync("burger", hash);
console.log(burger);  //always false
```

how does bcrypt actually compares the hash to the string?
Does it only look on the first 7 characters that are same?

thanks

Amit

Answer (score 4):

This is correct. Bcrypt is a salted hash and the salt is randomly generated. This means that each time you run the hash you will get a random result. This is intentional.

The part of the hash before the `.` (dot) and after the last `$` is the embedded salt. You don't need to store the salt separately since it is a part of the hash. Since the salt is correctly randomly generated you get full protection from rainbow table attacks.

The way bcrypt checks the hash is to first extract the embedded salt. Then run the string and salt through the algorithm again. If the resulting hash matches the hash then it passes.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yeah. It's something like that. Just don't remember the delimiter. I'll edit my answer